# Rally Rest Api: Java code to retrieve User Login History

Tags: rally

I am trying to fetch user login history from java rally-rest-api
I went through the rest-api documentation but there in user section.we don't have any attribute for user login date & time.

Please help.

Comment: You could rather edit the question with what you tried, in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The Last Login Date isn't an available field in Rally's Webservices API yet. This is a planned feature though. Keep an eye on Rally's ["What's New"](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/) feed to see when this feature is released. We'll try to update this post when the feature is available also.

Answer (score 0):

With Webservices API 1.42 released this week, `LastLoginDate` is now an available field on Rally Users, for Subscription and Workspace Administrators. You could now access this data via WSAPI 1.42+ using the [Java REST API](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api).